# sqlite read and write concurrently with php

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to write to a sqlite database after reading.
Here's the two sql statements,
1)I want to read some data

```
Select animalName ,longitude, latitude , cast(((strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - strftime('%s', time)) /(60  )) as timeDiff) as diff from Animal where localStatus=='locallyDisplayed' and diff > 30 ";
```

2)Then i want to update those selected data

```
UPDATE Animal SET localStatus='notlocallyDisplayed' where localStatus=='locallyDisplayed' and cast(((strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - strftime('%s', time)) /(60  )) as timeDiff) > 30  ";
```

Im getting a sqlite "**database locked error**" when trying to write(UPDATE).Can you please suggest a better way to handle this error. How can I unlock the database after reading(SELECT) so that I can write to the database(UPDATE) successfully.Im using php as the server side language.

Here's the code:

```
    $conn1 = new SQLite3('mydatabase.sqlite');

$sql1 = "Select animalName ,longitude, latitude , cast(((strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - strftime('%s', time)) /(60  )) as timeDiff) as diff from Animal where localStatus=='locallyDisplayed' and diff > 30 ";
$sql2 = "UPDATE Animal SET localStatus='notlocallyDisplayed' where localStatus=='locallyDisplayed' and cast(((strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - strftime('%s', time)) /(60  )) as timeDiff) > 30  ";

$result = $conn1->query($sql1);

$myArray = array(); 
while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {

    $myArray[] = $row;

}


$conn1->exec($sql2);
$conn1->close();
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Comment: It will help if you also show your PHP script that runs these 2 queries, that is where the issue will be

Comment: I have updated the question with code. Can you please tell how to handle the database locks with this transaction.

Comment: Some other connection (in this or in another process) still has an active transaction.